# Xib for custom UIView or UIView with class set to this custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I have created a custom `UIView` and I will need to add some controls to that `UIView`. I'm also using `storyboards` and I have to add this `UIView` to it.

My doubt if I have to create a xib for this custom `UIView` or it is better to add an `UIView` to the `storyboard` and change its type to my custom `UIView`.

And I have to get access to those control that I will add to the xib from custom `UIView`.

**What do you think?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i do/did

- Create a custom class as a subclass of UIView
- Everything is done programatically and initialization of variables is
  done with `-awakefromNib`
- In storyboard add the UIView
- Change its custom class to my  custom class name.
- Execute

and of course you can create a nib for the view and add controls and set connections to it and can be loaded from the nib name

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I set the connection from the controls to the custom UIView?

Comment: First make the nib uiview custom class as your class name then Iboutlets will be available

Comment: And If I create a nib, do I have to add a `UIView` to the storyboard on Interface Builder?

Comment: @VansFannel Depens on what exactly you mean. You can do in IB/Storyboard everything that you can do with a naked UIView object. You cannot setup any custom properties of your UIView subclass in IB. At least not as far as I know. You woudl have to setup those properties programmatically in viewDidLoad or so.